# Splitting distribution visualisations on the y-axis in ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

The most commonly cited example of how to visualize a logistic fit using ggplot2 seems to be something very much like this:

```
data("kyphosis", package="rpart")  
ggplot(data=kyphosis, aes(x=Age, y = as.numeric(Kyphosis) - 1)) +
      geom_point() + 
      stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial")
```

[image: plot image]

This visualisation works great if you don't have too much overlapping data, and the first suggestion for crowded data seems to be to use injected jitter in the x and y coordinates of the points then adjust the alpha value of the points. When you get to the point where individual points aren't useful but distributions of points are, is it possible to use geom_density(), geom_histogram(), or something else to visualise the data but continue to split the categorical variable along the y-axis as it is done with geom_point()?

From what I have found, geom_density() and geom_histogram() can easily be split/grouped by the categorical variable and both levels can easily be reversed using scale_y_reverse() but I can't figure out if it is even possible to move only one of the categorical variable distributions to the top of the plot. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "if it is even possible to move only one of the categorical variable distributions to the top of the plot" ??? Surely I miss something here but I am really lost.

Comment: As it stands now, the plot has points horizontally along the 0 and 1 lines (see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1189942/StackOverflow/logistic_points.png). I think they mean putting some sort of distribution plot (density, histogram, whatever) of age along the same lines, superimposing them on the graph.

Comment: Andrew is correct (and thanks for the image, I edited it in aboge), I'd like to replace those points with either a histogram or a density plot.

Comment: Perhaps doing it with a different package than ggplot is the way to go.

Comment: So essentially you're trying to do something like this, right? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1189942/StackOverflow/line_and_distributions.png

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `annotate()` function in ggplot allows you to add geoms to a plot with properties that ["are not mapped from the variables of a data frame, but are instead in as vectors,"](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/annotate.html) meaning that you can add layers that are unrelated to your data frame. In this case your two density curves *are* related to the data frame (since the variables are in it), but because you're trying to position them differently, using `annotate()` is useful.

Here's one way to go about it:

```
data("kyphosis", package="rpart")  
model.only <- ggplot(data=kyphosis, aes(x=Age, y = as.numeric(Kyphosis) - 1)) +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial")

absents <- subset(kyphosis, Kyphosis=="absent")
presents <- subset(kyphosis, Kyphosis=="present")

dens.absents <- density(absents$Age)
dens.presents <- density(presents$Age)

scaling.factor <- 10  # Make the density plots taller
model.only + annotate("line", x=dens.absents$x, y=dens.absents$y*scaling.factor) + 
  annotate("line", x=dens.presents$x, y=dens.presents$y*scaling.factor + 1)
```

[image: Good]

This adds two annotated layers with scaled density plots for each of the kyphosis groups. For the `presents` variable, `y` is scaled and increased by 1 to shift it up.

You can also fill the density plots instead of just using a line. Instead of `annotate("line"...)` you need to use `annotate("polygon"...)`, like so:

```
model.only + annotate("polygon", x=dens.absents$x, y=dens.absents$y*scaling.factor, fill="red", colour="black", alpha=0.4) + 
  annotate("polygon", x=dens.presents$x, y=dens.presents$y*scaling.factor + 1, fill="green", colour="black", alpha=0.4)
```

[image: Perfect]

Technically you could use `annotate("density"...)`, but that won't work when you shift the `present` plot up by one. Instead of shifting, it fills the whole plot:

```
model.only + annotate("density", x=dens.absents$x, y=dens.absents$y*scaling.factor, fill="red") + 
  annotate("density", x=dens.presents$x, y=dens.presents$y*scaling.factor + 1, fill="green")
```

[image: Bad]

The only way around that problem is to use a polygon instead of a density geom.

One final variant: flipping the top density plot along y-axis = 1:

```
model.only + annotate("polygon", x=dens.absents$x, y=dens.absents$y*scaling.factor, fill="red", colour="black", alpha=0.4) + 
  annotate("polygon", x=dens.presents$x, y=(1 - dens.presents$y*scaling.factor), fill="green", colour="black", alpha=0.4)
```

[image: Flipped]

Comment: Also, you'll need to adjust the axis ticks and scaling for the model or for the polygons. As it stands now, it looks like there are negative ages.

Comment: This is such a great answer, thank you. I hadn't thought of annotate and was afraid I'd end up recreating these in base graphics.

Comment: Before I remembered annotate, I was actually trying to create the density plots in base graphics, export them as PNG or PDF, and then place them as raster layers in ggplot. Way too complicated :)

Comment: I did manage to get somewhat close using base graphics and something similar to your solution, fitting each density individually and adding them to a plot of the regression result using lines(). It was not pretty, thanks again for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get your point, but here an attempt:

```
dat <- rbind(kyphosis,kyphosis)
dat$grp <- factor(rep(c('smooth','dens'),each = nrow(kyphosis)),
                  levels = c('smooth','dens'))
ggplot(dat,aes(x=Age)) +
      facet_grid(grp~.,scales = "free_y") +
      #geom_point(data=subset(dat,grp=='smooth'),aes(y = as.numeric(Kyphosis) - 1)) +
      stat_smooth(data=subset(dat,grp=='smooth'),aes(y = as.numeric(Kyphosis) - 1),
                  method="glm", family="binomial") +
      geom_density(data=subset(dat,grp=='dens'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @agstudy, I think this is in the right direction but I was hoping to keep the regression fit and the data summary in the same facet.